# What do we call the person who is doing small business?

Tags: word-choice

If a person is earning 5000 rupees monthly in a business, then can we call him a businessman? What are the words we use for different earners earning from hundreds to millions of rupees in a  business.If a person is running a shop (selling snacks and homemade items), then what do we call that person? Is it a kind of a business or not? and If a person is selling the same items on the road, can we call him a businessman?

Comment: Does the business belong to the person in question? If so, *small business owner* is pretty standard in the US.

Comment: What @onomatomaniak says. You can also use the term [_small businessman_](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22small+businessman%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), although many might prefer the more gender-neutral term.

Comment: There are a number of terms used to describe that person - each with its own meaning: *small business operator, proprietor, magnate, tycoon, founder, manager*, to name a few.  Perhaps a bit more context could help narrow down the type of business person you had in mind.

Answer (score 6):

A person who owns a small business is commonly called a 'small business owner' and it's fine to call the person a businessman as long as the person is indeed a **man**.

However in professional terminology business classes are defined by number of employees rather than revenue.

In professional terminology there are generally five business classes.

In the UK (and most of Europe) they are distinguished as:

Micro (less than 10 employees), Small (less than 50), Medium (less than 250), Large (less than 1000) and Enterprise (more than 1000)

Source: I worked in business services for a couple of years.

Comment: I like "small business owner" for two reasons quite apart from being gender neutral.  First it more clearly uses "small" to modify the business, as opposed to characterizing the person.  Second, it emphasizes the role as owner/entrepreneur (if that's what the OP is asking about).  The word "businessman" can be used to describe all sorts of employees, from account managers to directors.  IMHO success as a small business entrepreneur is something of true merit.

Answer (score 1):

A person doing any kind of business is a *businessman* (if it's a man) or a *businesswoman* (if it's a woman), be it someone who earns a mere $80 to someone who brings home $8000 per month.

Comment: Shaona, so you don't recognize any difference between "entrepreneur" and "businessman"?